# ESLint no-unused-vars and no-undef error but variable is used

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using ESLint to check my javascript code on build and I am getting a no-unused-vars error followed by a no-undef error for the same variable. I can't undertand how the variable can be both unused and undefined.

```
export function count(){
    if (counter > 3){
        const a = 'big';
    } else {
        const a = 'small';
    }
    return a;
}
```

Given the pseudode representation above I get the following errors from ESLint:

```
line 3 error  'a' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
line 5 error  'a' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
line 7 error  'a' is not defined             no-undef
```

Any ideas on how to get round this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` is block-scoped. So what you're doing there is creating an `a` within whichever block gets executed, not using it, letting it go out of scope, and then trying to return a *different* `a` that the function closes over (which will cause a `ReferenceError` if there is no `a` being closed over). The `return a;` line doesn't refer to the `a` declared within either of the blocks above it; that one has gone out of scope by then.

So instead:

```js
export function count() {
    const a = counter > 3 ? "big" : "small";
    return a;
}
```

or

```js
export function count() {
    let a; // Declared outside the blocks
    if (counter > 3) {
        a = "big";
    } else {
        a = "small";
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You define your const inside the if, it is not living in the function scope.

you need to define it like

```
 export function count(){
    let a;
    if (counter > 3){
        a = 'big';
    } else {
        a = 'small';
    }
    return a;
}
```

More info, read next chapters of
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures

Answer (score 0):

Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const